# Equal sized bins Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to build a view with `'n'` `number of equal sized bins.`

How can we have `Tableau` define the size of the bin automatically?

say like if the user inputs `Number_of_bins=5` on `sum(sales)`
the size of the bin should be automatically split. to the `number of bins.`